# Escaping escaped

Tags: php, mysql

I'm needing to PHP escape, the MySQL escape. The MySQL escape contains both star and backslash.

I've gotten the MySQL escape part correct and the MySQL query runs correctly. I am however struggling to escape the MySQL escape `"\*"` correctly in PHP. 
I've tried and looked at several example without any success.

Here's my code PHP code:

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from (select Date,DocketNo,StockCode,Description,Quantity,Dept,DeptName,LineTotal,CustNo,CustomerName 
                       from sales
                       where Date between '$datefrom' and '$dateto'
                       )
                 as T
        right join cust_repcode
        on cust_repcode.Customer = T.CustomerName       
        where RepCode ='$repcode' 
        and Date  is not Null
        and StockCode != '"\*"'
        Order by Date");
```

Comment: Why does `*` need to be escaped?

Comment: Solved 

StockCode != \"\\*\"

Comment: Thanks Chris for the response

The star needed to be escaped as it's a character used as a stock code.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. If you were using prepared statements and placeholder values none of this would be an issue.

Comment: @DeviPierre The `*` has no special meaning in a comparison in SQL. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a572d2/1 There is no reason `*` should be escaped in the code you've shown.

Comment: And PHP thinks it is two characters: clarification:  https://eval.in/642520. Note: proper escapes are only one character :) Just curious, what documentation lead you to doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need to escape the * in MySQL but if it needs, I would use the `CHAR()` method which looks cleaner

`and StockCode != CHAR(42)`